# How to make a preloader before web page even loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, preloader

I'd like to make a preloader bar that shows how much the page is loading before it is fully loaded (something like pushcollective.com, notice the upper bar before the page is fully load).

How can I achieve something like this? I imagine directing the user into a loading page first and request the page using AJAX and put the requested content into a `div` after it has finished loading. But I don't think that's a clean solution?

Comment: Your proposed solution of using a lightweight page to make AJAX requests for content, updating progress as each bit is received, and then assembling and displaying the content is a good one.  Why do you think this isn't "clean"?

Comment: show a progressbar and *fake* the percent loaded, then when it's done loading, quickly finish the load bar and show the content.

Comment: @Yuck: because it's just an idea, and i don't really know how to do it, maybe I shouldn't use the word clean after all, my mistake, english is not my primary language

Comment: I don't think that progress bar at pushcollective.com shows the actual loading status. I think that they randomly add values and when ajax response comes back they just fill it and hide it.

Comment: Having a page and requesting all its content in a single request its not the best way to do this. You can create your website as a Single Page Application and using subsequent requests you can load all the content needed: markup, data, images. This way, you can update the progress bar more accurately.

Answer (score 1):

The website you provided a link to (http://pushcollective.com/) uses [NProgress.js plugin](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/). As far as I was able to explore it uses random values to increment the progress bar (IMHO not a very elegant solution but I guess the only possible).
Here is a snippet from plugins code:

```
/**
 * Increments by a random amount.
 */

  NProgress.inc = function(amount) {
    var n = NProgress.status;

    if (!n) {
      return NProgress.start();
    } else {
      if (typeof amount !== 'number') {
        amount = (1 - n) * clamp(Math.random() * n, 0.1, 0.95);
      }

      n = clamp(n + amount, 0, 0.994);
      return NProgress.set(n);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't think of what I'm about to propose as of a 'clean' solution, however here's another approach without an extra AJAX call to load the page:

Separate your  content into two parts: a progress bar and everything else (which would be an actual page content). The progress bar is never-ending, filling logarithmically. The filling logic should be in an  tag placed right after your progress bar inside the . That way it will start working before everything's loaded, but after the progress bar appears.

Make the "actual content" block hidden initially. Subscribe to DOM Ready event. When it fires, hide the progress and show the content. Or you can show full progress for a split of a second and then hide it.

I don't think of the above as of 'clean', because it doesn't reflect actual progress, but it doesn't seem to do so in example you've mentioned either.

Comment: thanks, but this is exactly the first thing came to my mind, i throw it away because i need to show an actual progress

Comment: If you really need the actual progress, then the only option I see is do the following. Knowing more or less accurately the page content at development time, you may mark some points of the page to use them as loading milestones. Then, in the script I described in the answer, you could be polling these milestones by using `document.getElementById` or other means to check whether they've been loaded to DOM. When they have, you move the progress bar accordingly. It will work, but I personally would choose logarithmically-filled progress bar over this.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I came across with this simple and easy to use plugin for jQuery call PreLoadMe, I find it the Best so far:

http://niklausgerber.com/blog/preloadme-a-lightweight-jquery-website-preloader/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended with `pacejs`, it's pretty cool, easy to use, and easy to configure. You guys can check it out [here](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/), thanks for all the answer.